# Perform query if hash/checksum values are different in both tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, hash, changeset

I want to archive table1 to table2 based on changes to table1. (table2 being the archive table)

I have written a query which provides me with a checksum/hash of each table (which in effect tells me if the contents of tables have changed):

table1 = hash1 = CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)

table2 = hash2 = CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)

I want to write a Stored proc to do the following:

If these two hash values match then do nothing, if they now differ, then do query x.

How do I go about structuring this SQL query with **IF**'s and **Else**'s etc? Is there an optimal way of doing this without having to create separate tables/stored procs etc?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need?

```
IF HASH1 <> HASH2
BEGIN
 EXEC procname --This doesn't have to be a stored proc, could be a standalone statement
END
```

Comment: Not sure this will work, how do I get the IF statement to reference the hash1/2 columns of the select query?